# How to access class method and class variable from a class to another class's instance method in Python?

Tags: python, instance-methods

Imagine I have three classes as shown in the code snippet.

In class A, I have class variable and class method that I would like to access in class C after multiple inheritance, i.e., C(A,B) where B is just another class. I have found that I can access both class method and variable via **self.**, **super().** or by using the class name it self, i.e., **A.**

The question is, what could be the advised way to access, if any. Or, all three are equally fine?
Thanks in advance.
Regards,
DS

```
class A():
    school='XYZ'
    def __init__(self):
        print('in init A')
    def feature1(self):
        print('Feature1-A working')
    def feature2(self):
        print('Feature2-A working')

    @classmethod
    def show_avg(cls,m1,m2,m3):
        return (m1+m2+m3)/3
    @classmethod
    def info(cls):
        return cls.school

class B():
    def __init__(self):
        print('in init B')
    def feature3(self):
        print('Feature1-B working')
    def feature4(self):
        print('Feature2-B working')

class C(A,B):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print('in init C') 
    def get_avg_from_super_class(self):
        avg1=self.show_avg(2,3,4)
        avg2=super().show_avg(2,3,4)
        avg3=A.show_avg(2,3,4)
        print('avg by calling self:{}, avg by calling super():{}, avg by alling class name:{}'.format(avg1,avg2,avg3))
    def get_info(self):
        print (A.info())
        print(self.info())
        print(super().info())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your code, either of the three way works fine.
But in general, I would say using the class name to access *class methods* and *class variables* is the *safest* way to ensure you are accessing the right methods/variables.

For example,

1.If you have another `info()` in class `C` whether it's a *class method* or an *instance method*,

```
self.info()
```

will call that method defined in class `C`, NOT the one in class `A`

2.If the order of inheritance is different as to `class C(B, A)`, and you have another `info()` in class `B` whether it's a *class method* or an *instance method*,

```
super().info()
```

will call that method defined in class `B`, NOT the one in class `A`

Comment: Perhaps a correction needed? If one creates an object from class C and tries to access instance method from super class A, then accessing by class name does not work. It has to be self. Am I right?

Comment: @DebashishSaha You actually CAN access instance method by class name, but you won't be using it as "instance method", meaning you have to actually pass in an argument at `self` position.

Comment: Thanks. It works. Could you then please explain a bit why one should pass self as an argument to the method inherited from super class given the fact that super().__init__() is already there?

Comment: @DebashishSaha, When overriding the method? And also, in the method definition? or when the method is invoked?